# Renaming the Windows guest failed. Most often this is because you've specified a FQDN instead of just a host name

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-plugin

I am running vagrant version,

```
vagrant -v
Vagrant 1.9.3

vagrant plugin list
vagrant-butcher (2.2.1)
vagrant-cachier (1.2.1)
vagrant-omnibus (1.5.0)
vagrant-share (1.1.7, system)
vagrant-vbguest (0.13.0)
```

When I start a vagrant VM, windows 2012r2,

I get "Renaming the Windows guest failed. Most often this is because you've specified a FQDN instead of just a host name."

It used to work before on the same host(centos7, with Virtualbox) with version 1.4.

Comment: Do you understand the error message?  You have `hostname.example.com` in some setting where you should have just `hostname`.

Comment: It is working on vagrant 1.4 on other host running centOS 7 as base machine. Why not on 1.9.3

Comment: btw, I am using winrm and powerShell scripts to rename the VM

Comment: It is just a "suggestive"  message that is sometime misleading, because vagrant doesn't have the permission to rename the guest.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but is is breaking the  run, actually after he error the vagrant building should continue, but it just stops there. Next chef run should happen on the vagrant box, but it just breaks there

Comment: How can I fix the permissions ?

Comment: Any help please ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I’m having the same issue now.

Answer (score 3):

If you are (like me) experiencing this with Kitchen, in your .kitchen.yml, in the platform section, you can't have "name: mwrock/Windows2012R2". Instead, name it something like "windows2012R2" and, in platform's "driver_config" section, specify "box: mwrock/Windows2012R2".

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can resolve this issue is by setting the vm_hostname attribute to false like this:

```
platforms:
  - name: BPA-TEST
    driver_config:
      username: Tester
      password: [PASSWORD]
      vm_hostname: false
    driver:
      port: 55985
      customize:
        memory: 4048
```

https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-vagrant

> **vm_hostname** Sets the internal hostname for the instance. This is not used when connecting to the Vagrant virtual machine.
>
> To prevent this value from being rendered in the default Vagrantfile,
>   you can set this value to false.
>
> The default will be computed from the name of the instance. For
>   example, the instance was called "default-fuzz-9" will produce a
>   default vm_hostname value of "default-fuzz-9". For Windows-based
>   platforms, a default of nil is used to save on boot time and potential
>   rebooting.